# Support of the pushforward of structure sheaf of a smooth scheme along proper birational morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, coherent-sheaves

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$ and $R$ be a finite type $k$-algebra. Let $X$ be a smooth $k$-scheme and $f: X \to \text{Spec}(R)$ be a proper birational morphism.
Then, is the $R$-module $f_* \mathcal O_X$ supported at every maximal ideal of $R$, i.e., is the localization of $f_* \mathcal O_X$ non-zero at every maximal ideal of $R$ ?  If needed, I am willing to assume that $f_* \mathcal O_X$ is a projective $R$-module.

Comment: Do you know that $R$-modules are the same as locally free sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$? Also, if the fibers of $X \to \operatorname{Spec}(R)$ are connected, then $f_* \mathcal O_X = R$ (since $k$ has characteristic $0$).

Comment: @red_trumpet: $R$ is not regular, so I am not sure what you mean when you say that $R$-modules are locally free sheaves on $\text{Spec}(R)$...

Comment: Sorry, I was missing the word "projective". So projective $R$-modules are locally free sheaves. Even if $R$ is regular this is not true for arbitrary $R$-modules.

Comment: @red_trumpet You need to assume that $R$ is normal (i.e., integrally closed). In general, $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ will be the normalization of $R$.

Answer (score 1):

Proper + birational tells you that $f$ is surjective, so yes, $f_* \mathcal{O}_X$ will be supported on all of ${\rm Spec}(R)$.

The characteristic 0 assumption is not needed.